# Как удалить элемент из .json файла?

Tags: python, json

Имеется .json - файл в виде:

```json
{
  "personal": [
    {
      "name": "Вася",
      "salary": 5000
    },
    {
      "name": "Саша",
      "salary": 6000
    }
  ]
}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом можно удалить элемент из этого файла по ключу в Python?
Спасибо!

Comment: `json_data.pop('название_ключа')`

Answer (score 3):

Из вопроса не очень понятно, что вы пытаетесь удалить. Вот пример как удалить из первого элемента `salary`

```py
import json

a = '''{
  "personal": [
    {
      "name": "Вася",
      "salary": 5000
    },
    {
      "name": "Саша",
      "salary": 6000
    }
  ]}'''
dict_ = json.loads(a)

dict_["personal"][0].pop("salary")
print(dict_)
```

Что на выходе

```py
{'personal': [{'name': 'Вася'}, {'name': 'Саша', 'salary': 6000}]}
```

При работе с файлом

```py
import json

with open("test.json", encoding="utf8") as file:
    dict_ = json.load(file)

dict_["personal"][0].pop("salary")

with open("test.json", "w", encoding="utf8") as file:
    json.dump(dict_, file, ensure_ascii=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо всем за комментарии. Нашел следующий вариант (так как непонятно было, нужно ли удалять первый или какой-то неопределенный элемент .json - файла):

```py
user_for_del = str(input('Введите имя удаляемого сотрудника\n'))
print(user_for_del)
with open('personal.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:  # открыли файл
    data = json.load(f)  # загнали все из файла в переменную
minimal = 0
for txt in data['personal']:
    print('Запись №:', minimal)
    print(txt['name'], ':', txt['salary'])
    if txt['name'] == user_for_del:
      print('Запись будет удалена')
      data['personal'].pop(minimal)
    else:
      None
    minimal = minimal + 1
print('Итоговый результат: ')
print(data)
print('А теперь записываем итоговый файл')
with open('personal.json', 'w', encoding='utf8') as outfile:
    json.dump(data, outfile, ensure_ascii=False, indent=2)
```

Благодаря этой конструкции можно шерстить .json - файл, находить нужные записи и удалять ... не думаю, что изобрел велосипед, но все же :)

Answer (score 1):

```py
import json
a = """{
  "personal": [
    {
      "name": "Вася",
      "salary": 5000
    },
    {
      "name": "Саша",
      "salary": 6000
    }
  ]}"""

def to_fire_employee(fired_employee_name: str):
    data = json.loads(a)
    data['personal'] = list(
        filter(
            lambda x: x.get('name') != fired_employee_name, 
            data.get('personal', [])
        )
    )
    return json.dumps(data, ensure_ascii=False)

print(
    to_fire_employee('Вася')
)
# {"personal": [{"name": "Саша", "salary": 6000}]}
```

---

Или можно "увольнять" списком:

```py
def to_fire_employee(fired_employee_list: list):
    data = json.loads(a)
    data['personal'] = list(
        filter(
            lambda x: x.get('name') not in fired_employee_list,
            data.get('personal', [])
        )
    )
    return json.dumps(data, ensure_ascii=False)

print(
    to_fire_employee(['Вася'])
)
```

> Можно скомбинировать 2 вышеописанных варианта

```
from typing import Union
import json

def to_fire_employee(fired: Union[list, str]):
    if isinstance(fired, list):
        ff = lambda x: x.get('name') not in fired
    else:
        ff = lambda x: x.get('name') != fired

    data = json.loads(a)
    data['personal'] = list(
        filter(
            ff,
            data.get('personal', [])
        )
    )
    return json.dumps(data, ensure_ascii=False)

print(
    to_fire_employee('Вася')
)
```